# Adding direction arrow to current location on Mapbox (iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, mapbox

I have an app that uses `Mapbox` to present a map with the user location, it looks like this:

[image: Mapbox]

I want to add a direction arrow to the current location marker that shows you the direction you're walking to, like that:

[image: With arrow]

Does anybody know how can I add this arrow using `Mapbox iOS SDK`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Mapbox Maps SDK for iOS v3.6.3 or newer it’s possible to add an always-on heading indicator using [`MGLMapView.showsUserHeadingIndicator`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.7.2/Classes/MGLMapView.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLMapView(py)showsUserHeadingIndicator). With this setting enabled, the user location annotation will look like this:

[image: stroked-arrow]

Also see [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/user-location-annotation/) for how to implement this in a *custom* user location annotation.

*Old answer below, for posterity.*

---

Custom user location annotation views are a feature of the upcoming v3.4.0 release, which you can try out now in [pre-release](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/releases/tag/ios-v3.4.0-beta.1).

You may find the SDK’s default implementation of [`MGLUserLocationAnnotationView`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.4.0-beta.1/Classes/MGLUserLocationAnnotationView.html), [`MGLFaux3DUserLocationAnnotationView`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/0208dc283376f8de6038512a698b0ce379a5b415/platform/ios/src/MGLFaux3DUserLocationAnnotationView.m), useful in constructing your own.

As for adding an always-on heading indicator, that’s [not yet possible](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/5523) with `MGLMapView`’s location manager — for now, you will need to get the heading from your own location manager when the tracking mode is not `.FollowWithHeading`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I saw you are one of the `Mapbox` team. I have another question about `Mapbox` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40317861/dynamically-change-mglpointannotation-image-on-mapbox-ios-sdk), can you please take a look? Thanks!

Comment: I accepted your answer, but can you please help me on the second one? Thanks!