# Dynamically change MGLPointAnnotation image on Mapbox iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, mapbox

I have an app that uses a map of `Mapbox` on its `iOS SDK` and present markers (`MGLPointAnnotation`) on it.

I want to change the image of a marker when it selected.

`MGLPointAnnotation` has no `image` property and I've tried to call the delegate method `mapView(mapView, imageForAnnotation annotation)` but it didn't work.

Any idea how can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: I would think calling mapView.removeAnnotation(myAnnotation) and then immediately call mapView.addAnnotation(myAnnotation) would force it to call imageForAnnotation again..?

Answer (score 1):

1. I'm pretty sure that there is no way to change an annotation after is has been added to the map (except it is an annotationView)
2. The `mapView(mapView, imageForAnnotation annotation)` gets only called, when you add an annotation.
3. What you can do is to to use the didselect delegete

   `func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didSelect annotationView: MGLAnnotationView){ //code 
   }`

And set there a new annotation at the same location but this time with your desired image. Then the image annotation delegate gets called, where you define your image

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, imageFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationImage? {
//code
}
```

Here's an example for a customer marker image: https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/marker-image/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to change the image when you click on a different image.

```
var poiSelected: MGLAnnotation?

private func printPoiImage(with name: String, annotation: MGLAnnotation, mapView: MGLMapView) {
    let id = "\(annotation.coordinate.latitude)+\(annotation.coordinate.longitude)"
    let annotationImage = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationImage(withIdentifier: id)
    annotationImage?.image = UIImage(named: name)
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didSelect annotation: MGLAnnotation) {
        if self.poiSelected == nil {
            self.poiSelected = annotation
            self.printPoiImage(with: "PoiOn", annotation: annotation, mapView: mapView)
        }
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didDeselect annotation: MGLAnnotation) {
        self.poiSelected = nil
        self.printPoiImage(with: "PoiOff", annotation: annotation, mapView: mapView)
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, imageFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationImage? {
        let id = "\(annotation.coordinate.latitude)+\(annotation.coordinate.longitude)"

        var annotationImage = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationImage(withIdentifier: id)

        if annotationImage == nil {

            var image: UIImage?
            if self.poiSelected == nil {
                image = UIImage(named: "PoiOff")
            } else {
                image = UIImage(named: "PoiOn")
            }

            guard var imageWrap = image else { return nil }
            imageWrap = imageWrap.withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: imageWrap.size.height/2, right: 0))
            annotationImage = MGLAnnotationImage(image: imageWrap, reuseIdentifier: id)
        }

        return annotationImage
    }
```